# QR code automation using selenium and appium

Tags: selenium, cordova

I trying to automate a cordova application.
Im able to automate all the functionalities. But at one point, camera opens up and asks to scan the QR code. 
Once the QR code is scanned it will be converted to a string and sent to server using some web service which will return the name of the user.

When the server returns the name of the user the app will continue with normal execution.

Question:

I want to skip this manual scanning of QR code.
I have the string that will be generated when the QR code is scanned and I want to directly get the name of the user. I can get that name using web service automation, but how do I make it reach to the application.

Answer (score 0):

Even we were facing the same issue. The best thing to automate this manual scanning process is to buy a car phone holder with long flexible string. Now stick it somewhere around the **wall/cubicle/CPU** such that your device(mobile) is always kept facing your PC monitor. Display QR code image in your PC monitor whenever required and of course that should be controlled by your automation script. You're done!!!

Basically your script will open the QR code image as per the test steps, and since your device is facing the PC monitor, the goal is achieved.

Comment: I can't tell if this is a serious answer or not.

Comment: Looks like a feasible solution.

Comment: it must be joke :)